# Program for identifying files from unfinished torrent-downloads?

Tags: files, search, bittorrent

Are there any programs that can help identify files and directories belonging to unfinished bittorrent-downloads?  I've made a mess, and I'm unsure of which downloads are finished and which are not.  I could obviously use the bt-client, if I still had the torrent-files, but I don't.  I'm therefor looking for way to identify *likely* unfinished bt-downloads - doesn't have to be 100% accurate.

I've noticed that bt-clients typically create empty-files, as well as leave files with "holes" (blocks of the file with just NULL-characters), so this could perhaps be a good way to find likely candidates.  Sadly, I don't know any good Linux-commands for finding files with blocks of NULLs...

Comment: It'd be a good idea to add name/version of your client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your grep supports it; you could do a check by grep.

```
grep -P '\x00{NNN}' File
```

Where NNN is how many continuously zero bytes you want to match. 
Would typically be max USHRT_MAX or 65535.

`-P` is needed to use `\x00`

To list offsets use:

```
grep -Pboa '\x00{NNN}' File
```

So something in the direction of:

```
for f in *; do
    [ -e "$f" ] || break
    if grep -Pq '\x00{1000}' "$f"; then 
        mv "$f" ../likely_corrupt
    fi
done
```

---

Else you could use `hexdump`, `xxd` or the like and match for `000...`.

```
hexdump -ve '/1 "%02X"'
```

But that would be crazy slow.

---

<sub>Finally a very short C program could do the same.</sub>